# Java graphical user interface

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I want to add two strings in java by getting data from two input fields. Result is shown in the 3rd field. I am using this code, but netbeans shows an error:

```
float num1,num2,result;
num1=Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
num2=Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
result=num1+num2;
jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: This code is for Add button butt when I press button show lot of thread and in out put this message is show Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Ahsan"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)

Comment: Yes post the error and don't use the Netbeans GUI builder (IMO)

Comment: _"Ahsan"_ is _not_ a number. `NumberFormatException` clearly states that.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing which text fields are which. From the name of your variables, it looks like you're using GUI Builder. You should give your variables more semantic values like `nameField` so you know which one is which. You can do that by just right clicking the component from the design view and change variable name from the popup menu.

Comment: Yes I know that butt I want to add 2 strings

Comment: Two strings into the same text field?

Answer (score 2):

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

You will get a `NumberFormatException` if the text you entered isn't a proper number.Surround the `parseFloat()` statements in `try-catch` block. "Ahsan" isn't a number and hence cannot be parsed.

Make this little modification to your code:

```
try{
   num1=Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
   num2=Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
   result=num1+num2;
   jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But but, in farci, "Ashan" is translated to five, so why won't it work?!  kidding. +1

Comment: @peeskillet because swag. xD

Comment: Yes you are right but I want to add 2 strings and get as one string

Answer (score 1):

If you get `NumberFormatException` it can happen in one of these 2 lines:

```
num1=Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
num2=Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
```

More specifically it is thrown from `Float.parseFloat()`. You pass unparsable value to this method. Check what `jTextField1.getText()` or `jTextField2.getText()` return. I believe that these fields are empty or contain text that cannot be interpreted as legal `float`.